# Spring-data fails to update object with id 0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I've the following entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Item {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private String name;
    //getters & setters
}
```

A standard repo:

```
public interface Repo extends CrudRepository<Item, Long> {}
```

A simple restController:

```
@RestController
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    private Repo repo;

    @GetMapping("1")
    public Iterable<Item> getItems1() {
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setId(1);
        item.setName("name1");
        repo.save(item);

        item = new Item();
        item.setId(1);
        item.setName("name11");
        repo.save(item);

        return repo.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("0")
    public Iterable<Item> getItems0() {
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setId(0);
        item.setName("name0");
        repo.save(item);

        item = new Item();
        item.setId(0);
        item.setName("name00");
        repo.save(item);

        return repo.findAll();
    }
}
```

Dependencies: spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-starter-data-jpa, & com.h2database:h2.

Testing:

```
curl -si http://localhost:8080/1
HTTP/1.1 200
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

[{"id":1,"name":"name11"}]

curl -si http://localhost:8080/0
HTTP/1.1 500
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close

{"timestamp":"2019-05-09T16:45:01.734+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [test.Item#0]; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [test.Item#0]","path":"/0"}
```

**Why does storing with id 1 (or any other id) work & correctly update the entity, while storing with id 0 always fails at the second storage?**

I googled the exception and understand it's probably got to do with hibernate thinking it's an uninitialized id? But wasn't able to understand the exact logic on how it got into this exception.

Stack Trace:

```
javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [test.Item#0]
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:790) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:768) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:305) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy74.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:490) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_202]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:641) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:590) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at test.Controller.getItems0(Controller.java:37) ~[classes/:na] <-- when saving (0, "item00")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the implementation of `SimpleJpaRepository.save`

```java
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {

    if (entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Than check `AbstractEntityInformation.isNew`. It concludes that the entity is new only if its it is null (or 0 for numerical types).

You have 2 options to deal with this situation:

- use `entityManager.persist` or `entityManager.merge` instead of spring data repository
- derive from `org.springframework.data.domain.Persistable` and implement `isNew()`

Comment: Thank you so much!